# Use the value entered in a JSF page for Java Applet

Tags: jsf, applet

I have created a JSF page which asks the user to enter a value, and this value is being processed via Applet and create a barcode image based on the inputted value. My problem is how can i get the value from the JSF Page and use it in my Applet.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use JavaScript. E.g.

```html
<h:inputText ... onchange="updateBarcodeApplet(this.value)" />
...
<applet id="barcodeApplet" ...></applet>
```

with this JS

```html
<script>
    function updateBarcodeApplet(value) {
        var barcodeApplet = document.getElementById("barcodeApplet");
        barcodeApplet.updateValue(value);
    }
</script>
```

and in Applet

```
public void updateValue(String value) {
    // Do your business here.
}
```

*(yes, all Applet's public methods are just available as is in JS)*

Needless to say, using an applet for this job is pretty clumsy. Not all clients support or even appreciate applets. I'd also opt for a simple `<img>` element with a servlet which returns the image as suggested by Denisk. You just have to update the `<img src>` by JSF or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do it in a hard way? You don't really want an applet here, create the image on server, serialize it to response stream and display it as plain image.